# Do menus normally have icons in elementary OS?

Tags: release-freya, design

When I am working with eclipse, I am used to see symbols in the menu bars.
For example I open eclipse and click on the button "File" then it shows me the menu from File. But left from the texts are no symbols.

For example: Normally left from the Text "Save" is a little diskette symbol.

Comment: Nobody knows a solution, or is it normal, that there no symbols in the menus of eOS?

Greets

Answer (score 2):

Menu items in elementary OS do not normally have icons.

Comment: can icons be enabled for Files in Loki?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly this was a design decision of the GTK+ project.  You shouldn't see the menu icons in elementary OS nor in any other desktop environment that uses it (like GNOME).