# Enabling context menu icons in Pantheon Files?

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files, dconf

There are no icons in Files' context menus in Loki, and [this is normal](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1923/170) behavior.

Installing PCManFM those icons are still missing, but they can be enabled as explained [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/8773/170). The change doesn't affect Pantheon Files though, and I would like to have that, because my menus contain multiple entries that are much easier to spot and select when they have icons, as they do in other desktop environments.

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to trigger that change for the default file manager too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would need changing Files code so cannot be done by the user.

There is an existing bug report about icons in context menu - #1542709 - so this feature may be implemented in future.